# How to make videogular2 HLS working on IOS?

Tags: javascript, angular, videogular

I'm using [videogular2](https://github.com/videogular/videogular2) to display HLS on an Angular 6. It's working on desktop or Android mobiles, but I have the following error on IOS :

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.medias.toArray()[0].elem')
```

Here is my template :

```
<div>
    <vg-player>
      <video [vgHls]="url" id="singleVideo" controls crossorigin>
      </video>
    </vg-player>
</div>
```

Verions used :

"hls.js": "^0.11.0",

"videogular2": "^6.3.0"

Comment: Wasn't a controls issue for me, turns out I needed to add `#media [vgMedia]="media"` to the video element. That did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a way to make it work. It seems that it is the basic controls that cause the bug. Adding a custom controls fix the issue :

```
<vg-player>
<vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
<vg-buffering></vg-buffering>

<vg-controls>
  <vg-play-pause vgFor="singleVideo"></vg-play-pause>

  <vg-scrub-bar>
    <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
    <vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time></vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time>
  </vg-scrub-bar>

  <vg-time-display vgProperty="left" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>

  <vg-mute></vg-mute>
  <vg-volume></vg-volume>

  <vg-fullscreen></vg-fullscreen>
</vg-controls>

<video #media [vgMedia]="media" [vgHls]="url" id="singleVideo" autoplay>
</video>
```